# Flatten Nested JSON to Create a DataFrame

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested dictionary of no fixed format,for example as shown below:

```
    response = {
    'col_A':{'A': 'ab'},
    'col_B':'XY',
    'col_M':[1,3,4,2,5],
    'col_N':'YZ',
    'col_O':[{'C':'cd', 'D':'gh'},  {'C':'de', 'D':'hi'}, {'C':'ij', 'D':'jk', 'E':'ef'}, {'C':'ef', 'D':'fg', 'E':'kl'}],
    'col_F':[["2018-12-31",2,3,4], ["2018-12-30",7,6,8], ["2018-12-29",12,145,131], ["2018-12-28", 23.5, 435, 65.4]]
    }
```

The JSON response as we can see is just an example, and the nested level can be of any form.

Now for this JSON, I want the flattened dataframe like this:

| col_A_A | col_B | col_C | col_D | col_E_cd | col_E_de | col_E_ij | col_E_ef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ab | XY | [1,3,4,2,5] | YZ | 2018-12-31 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| ab | XY | [1,3,4,2,5] | YZ | 2018-12-30 | 7 | 6 | 8 |
| ab | XY | [1,3,4,2,5] | YZ | 2018-12-29 | 12 | 145 | 131 |
| ab | XY | [1,3,4,2,5] | YZ | 2018-12-28 | 23.5 | 435 | 65.4 |

Something like this should be the output in the form of pandas DataFrame.

In this question, if you see, a few keys in the dictionary are ignored and not being added in the DataFrame- `D` & `E` and for one of the `key`, its `value` is being added in the name of the column rather then appending key, for example, `C` in `col_E`.

So, the function should be robust to adapt these, and these values can be passed as parameter to the function.

Code which I have tried so far:

```
def flatten_json(nested_json, exclude=[''], include=None):
    """
    Flatten json object with nested keys into a single level.
        Args:
            nested_json: A nested json object.
            exclude: Keys to exclude from output.
        Returns:
            The flattened json object if successful, None otherwise.
    """
    out=dict()
    def flatten(x, name='', exclude=exclude, include=include):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude:
                    if a in include:
                        if name=='':
                            name = a
                        else:
                            name += "_"+a
                        if name not in out:
                            if type(x)!=list:
                                out[name] = [x[a]]
                            else:
                                out[name] = x[a] 
                        exclude.append(a)
                        flatten(x[a], name, exclude=exclude, include=[i for i in include if i!=a])
                    else:
                        print(a)
                        flatten(x[a], name + a + '_', exclude=exclude, include=include)
        elif type(x) is list:
            if x in out.values():
                pass
            else:
                x_ele = [each for each in x if type(x)!= list and type(x)!= dict]
                x_list = [each for each in x if type(x)== list or type(x)== dict]
                if len(x_list)==0:
                    if name.endswith("_"):
                        name = name[:-1]
                    if name not in include:
                        if name not in out:
                            if type(x)!=list:
                                out[name] = [x]
                            else:
                                out[name] = x
                        else:
                            out[name].append(x)
                elif len(x_list) == len(x) and name not in include and type(x_list[0])!=dict:
                    if type(x)!=list:
                        out[name] = [x]
                    else:
                        out[name] = x
                else:
                    for a in x:
                        flatten(a, name, exclude=exclude, include=include)
        else:
            if name.endswith("_"):
                name = name[:-1]
            if name not in out:
                if type(x)!=list:
                    out[name] = [x]
                else:
                    out[name] = x
            else:
                out[name].append(x)
    flatten(nested_json, exclude=exclude, include=include)
    return out
```

The above code should be called as:

```
flatten_json(response, exclude=['D', 'E', ''], include=['C'])
```

Below is the output:

```
{'col_A_A': ['ab'],
 'col_B': ['XY'],
 'col_M_': [1, 3, 4, 2, 5],
 'col_N': ['YZ'],
 'col_O__C': ['cd', 'cd'],
 'col_F_': [['2018-12-31', 2, 3, 4],
  ['2018-12-30', 7, 6, 8],
  ['2018-12-29', 12, 145, 131],
  ['2018-12-28', 23.5, 435, 65.4]]}
```

***Note***: Also, the above code is not very clean, after getting to the solution, I will clean up the code

Comment: So what's the problem? I don't see any questions here, remember SO is _not_ a code writing service.

Comment: if you have not fixed format then you should create own function which uses `if/elif/else` to run different code for different format in row.

Comment: I have tried, and the solution is close to it but not exactly as I needed. Please see the code above which I have tried.